# import Virtualbox disc with snapshot

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have a **VirtualBox discimage and a snapshot** of the current state.

How do I import them to my current Installation?

I tried to create a new machine, creating a snapshot and replacing this to files by mine. But there were some weird errors. I also tried to merge the disc image with the snapshot but the VirtualBoxManager says they are not in the media registry.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to this guy: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=63876&p=300134#p300134

I was able to merge my disc and the snapshot to a new disc, which I could then simply set as a new disc to a new machine.

This was possible using this tool: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=22422